# Should I leave bolts in frame when I've removed component (mudguards for example)

Tags: frames, titanium

I've just remove my mudguards from my Ti frame and as usual I have put the bolts back into the frame where the thread goes into a tube - for example in the chain-stay bridge and brake bridge.
I used anti-seize on the threads and did not do them up tight.

Should I be doing this?

I do it because it looks a bit neater and I suppose to stop water getting int but I thought that maybe I am just risking ruining my frame if the bolt gets stuck in there.

Thanks

Comment: I've always left the bolts on, cleaner look, prevents water and dirt damaging the screw threads in case I want to use them again (on a regular aluminum bike)

Comment: The bolt shouldn't get stuck in the frame, even if you torque the sh*t out of it. And like @Max said, it will protect the threads.

Comment: If you want to save weight there are plastic/nylon bolts. If you lose one of these you still have the originals safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually plug the hole with appropriate size hardware. I add a dab of anti-seize   compound. My reasoning (other than appearance) is that while the frame is aluminum or carbon the threaded insert is typically steel and there fore subject to rust.

Answer (score 2):

I leave mudguard, waterbottle mount etc. bolts in the frame, with appropriate grease, anti-seize applied. I do this mostly so I can find them when I need to mount the component again.

Comment: Concur - its easier to lose a bolt than the whole bike.

Answer (score 2):

You should plug the with something for two reasons:

1) to prevent water ingress into the frame

2) the brazing or frame threads are usually bare metal so they will rust easily

It’s easy to put a bolt into them or a plastic or rubber plug (if you’re a weight weenie)